# Abelian Group with basis $A \times B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I read about the following. Let $A,B$ be $\mathbb{Z}$-Modules. Then there exists an abelian group $C$ with basis $A \times B$. A R-module $D$ has a basis $\beta$, if the following mapping is an isomorphism: $$\alpha: \bigoplus_{b \in \beta} R \to D, (z_b) \mapsto \sum_{b \in \beta} z_bb.$$ I can't figure out a fitting isomorphism that has that property for the case above. I'm not sure whether I am overseeing something trivial or whether this is not too easy to see. Anyways, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yet, it is very simple: for any set $X$, a $\mathbf Z$-module with basis $X$ is simply the group $\mathbf Z^{(X)}$ of maps  $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbf Z$ with *finite support*.

An obvious basis  is the set of functions $\{e_x: x\in X\}$, where
\begin{cases}
e_x (x)=1,\\ e_x(y)=0& \text{if }y\ne x,
\end{cases}
in other words the characteristic function of the singleton $\{ x \}$.

The points in $X$ and these characteristic functions are usually identified, and we speak of the ‘free abelian group with basis $X$’.

Comment: Thank you for your Comment. Could you specify what you mean with identify? From what I can tell, I now need to find an isomorphism from the set you just gave, precisely the set of maps with finite support mapping to X.

Comment: From the point of view of set theory, $\displaystyle\bigoplus\limits_{b\in \beta}R$ *is* $R^{(\beta)}$, so it is  not an isomorphism, but an equality – just a notational problem, unless I've misunderstood what you're asking for.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something as well. We found an Isomorphism from $\bigsu_{b \in \beta} R$ to $R^{(\beta)}$ namely the one you gave above. In order for $X$ to be a basis however, I need to find an Isomorphism to a module that contains $X$ and is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{b \in \beta} R$. However, $R^{(\beta)}$ does not contain X. What I am missing is precisely the isomorphism in the form of the deifnition I gave above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: $R^{(\beta)}$ does not contain $X$,  except if $\beta =X$, via the correspondence $x\mapsto e_x$. With more familair notations, perhaps, an element of $R^{(X)}$ is just a family of elements of $R$: $(r_x)_{x\in X}$, where almost all $r_x $ are $0$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't see how this gives me the isomorphism I need, I'm sorry. Perhaps it would help if you would give the isomorphism from $\bigoplus_{b \in \beta}R$ to $A$, where $A$ is a $R$-module containing $X$ and having X as a basis, which ,correct me if I am wrong, is necessarily what I need, in order to show what I want.

Comment: What you don't, I think, is that, in the construction I posted, $\bigoplus_{b\in\beta}R$ *is * $A$, so the isomorphism is the identity map. Or is there something I don't see, among your objections?